# Using fgets() right after getchar()

Tags: c, input, fgets, getchar

```
void
read_stdin(trace_t* trace, state_t state, action_t** action_list) {
    // initial stage
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar())!= EOF && c!='#') {
        if (my_isalpha(c)==LOWERCASE) {
            state[c-ASCII_CODE_LOWER_A] = '1';
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", state);

    char str[2];
    fgets(str, 2, stdin);
    printf("%s", str);
}
```

If '#' is the last character I enter in the getchar() loop, fgets() records the newline character from when I press enter and skips to the print statement immediately (which prints the '\n')

I could fix this by adding an additional fgets()(which has to have a string that is longer than 1 char passed to it for some reason?) but is there a more elegant way of solving this?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can use `scanf("%*[\n]");` to ignore *any number* of consecutive newline. Or `scanf("%*1[\n]");` for eating only *one* newline. If any other character is the first one, it is not consumed.

Another option would be to use low-level operations `getchar` and `ungetc`:

```
int eat_stdin_newline(void) {
    int ch = getchar();
    if (ch != EOF && ch != '\n') {
        // if it wasn't EOF or newline, push it back...
        ungetc(ch, stdin); // must succeed
    }
    return ch;
}
```

Then you can call this function wherever you want:

```
eat_stdin_newline();
```